# Can you suffer bufferbloat when using only 1/4th of your bandwidth?

Tags: networking, performance, internet, bandwidth, bufferbloat

As the title suggests, is it possible to have bufferbloat without hitting your max download or upload speeds (on Ethernet)? I have recently moved into a new house and asked for the internet to be upgraded to 250/40 package which speedtest shows is realistically reaching 270/45 sometimes 280/50 (download/upload).

The problem is that I'm experiencing what feels like bufferbloat even when I am uploading at only 10-12 Mbps or 1/4th of the upload bandwidth (Streaming to Twitch.tv). Here are the signs of it:

- My main game shows a "Packet Burst" icon often - unsure about the meaning, just know its name from the internet
- My main game's metrics for latency and packet loss are normal - 0% packet loss, <30ms latency.
- Websites load quite a bit slower, sometimes seconds slower
- Housemates reporting slowdowns and poor performance in general
- http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest gives me a grade of B for bufferbloat

The above issues disappear when I am not streaming, even though the stream is only 1/4 of the total bandwidth. Is this normal? As far as I understand, bufferbloat is supposed to happen only when maxing out the connection. Is it possible my ISP's network is so bad, that this is happening anyway?

What tests can I perform to determine whether this is bufferbloat or something else?

Thanks

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Ethernet

Comment: This isn't normal. What's the router make model? Sorry to take so long to respond.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It's ok. It's BT Smart Hub 2.